# HTML. How to stop redirecting after form successfully completed?

Tags: php, html, mysql, forms, redirect

I have simple HTML form for add new user. After submit button is clicked It starts PHP file (inserting to MySQL database, etc), but auto redirecting to add_user.php

This is HTML file:

```
<html>
<form method="post" action="add_user.php">
First name: <input type="text" name="vardas"><br>
Kast name: <input type="text" name="pavarde"><br>
<input type="submit" value="Add user">
</form>
</html>
```

I need to make that after submit button is clicked PHP file will be used, but It should stay on the same HTML file (not redirect) for adding more users and need to show message something like "User added successfully".

Comment: put the php code in the same page and change the form action to `action="#"` or have a look into AJAX

Comment: You can perfect output the form in your add_user.php file, where you check wether a POST is set or not.

Comment: The search term you are looking for is *Ajax*. There are many tutorials out there. Writing another one to answer this question would be too broad for Stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST' && isset($_POST['vardas'])) {
  //COPY CONTENTS OF add_user.php HERE
  $success = "User inserted successfully";
} 
?>

<html>
<?php
if(isset($success)){
  echo $success;
}
?>
<form method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">
First name: <input type="text" name="vardas"><br>
Kast name: <input type="text" name="pavarde"><br>
<input type="submit" value="Add user">
</form>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to use ajax or json to send data to php page. also for prevent from form submit need to right return false.

ex

```
$(document).on('submit', "#form", function() {

// do your ajax stuff
return false;
});
```

Comment: Given jQuery, you should rather use eventArgument.preventDefault(), so that other event handlers will still get the event. `return false` will stop the event from bubbling up the DOM.